# Word Patterns for Cryptography

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want a function f that takes a word (like those listed in WordList[]) and returns a pattern best described by examples like these:
f[“book”]=abbc;  f[“settings”]=abccdefa; and f[“moving”]=abcdef.

Then I want a second function, f2, that searches a list of words for words that have the same pattern, returning a list of them; for example f2[WordList[],abcdefabgd]={liberalize, roisterous, stochastic}

The motive is to write a program that solves substitution ciphers, but could have other uses too!

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for? What is the logic behind "book" equalling abba?

Comment: @bills probably book -> abbc ?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo; book->abbc

Answer (score 5):

You can split the string and turn it into a pattern like this:

```
makePattern[word_String] := StringExpression @@ Map[
  With[{s = Symbol @ #}, Pattern[s, Blank[]]] &,
  Characters[word]];

findMatches[word_String, list_List : WordList[]] := 
  Select[list, StringMatchQ[makePattern @ word]];
```

Which gives you

```
findMatches @ "settings"
```

> {"diffused", "golliwog", "greening", "greeting", "grooming", 
>   "grooving", "guzzling", "littoral", "rollover", "succubus", 
>   "suppress", "syllabus"}

Answer (score 3):

```
f1 = "" <> Alphabet[][[ArrayComponents @ Characters @ #]] &;

f2 = GroupBy[f1];
```

Use:

```
f1 /@ {"book", "settings", "moving"}
```

> ```
> {"abbc", "abccdefa", "abcdef"}
> ```

```
allwords = DictionaryLookup[];

find = f2[allwords];  (* cache lookup table for all patterns *)

find["abcdefabgd"]
```

> ```
> {"liberalize", "stochastic"}
> ```

(I don't have `WordList` in v10.1.0 so I substituted [`DictionaryLookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DictionaryLookup.html).)

Although it is *much better* to cache `find` as shown above this works without `f2`:

```
DictionaryLookup[x__ /; f1[x] === "abcdefabgd"]
```

> ```
> {"liberalize", "stochastic"}
> ```

---

#### Performance

Although it should not matter if you only build `find` once as shown, [`ArrayComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayComponents.html) proves to be a bottleneck in my `f1` code.  Here is a more verbose equivalent that is an order of magnitude faster, should it matter.

```
f1fast =
  With[{cc = ToCharacterCode @ #},
    cc
      // DeleteDuplicates
      // AssociationThread[# -> Take[Alphabet[], Length@#]] &
      // Lookup[cc]
      // StringJoin
  ] &;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more robust variation of [mvonh's fine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138496/531) which uses [`Unique`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unique.html) to ensure that the symbols used to mark patterns don't collide with variables that have values.

```
makePattern[word_String] :=
 With[{chars = Characters@word},
  Apply[
   StringExpression, 
   chars /. 
    AssociationMap[With[{s = Unique@#}, Pattern[s, Blank[]]] &, 
     DeleteDuplicates@chars]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a function to code the words:

```
code[word_] := Module[{},
  split = Characters[word];
  numLetters = Length@Tally[split];
  subs = Thread[Tally[split][[All, 1]] -> Range[numLetters]];
  subs2 = Thread[Range[numLetters] -> CharacterRange["a", "z"][[1 ;; numLetters]]];
  StringJoin[split /. subs /. subs2]]
```

So for example

```
code["abandonment"]
"abacdecfgch"
```

Then we can search the dictionary using `Nearest` with a custom distance function:

```
dist[w1_, w2_] := EditDistance[code[w1], code[w2]];

allWords = WordList[];
Nearest[allWords, "abandonment", 5, DistanceFunction -> dist]   

{"abandonment", "analogously", "condensing", "consenting", "nonadjacent"}
```

Showing that these are the 5 nearest words to "abandonment" using the `code` notion of distance. Or, if you want only those that have exactly the same form,

```
Select[WordList[], code[#] == code["settings"] &]
```